# What is an extra low voltage circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, terminology, low-voltage

I am a novice in power electronics. I don't know when we can call a circuit an extra-low-voltage circuit. for example a circuit in which there's a power supply that converts 240V AC to 24V DC and other components working with 24V DC, is it  an extra-low-voltage circuit? the input voltage of the power supply is higher than  the extra-low-voltage range but the output of power supply is in the range of extra-low-voltage. Is this circuit considered as an extra-low-voltage one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really comes down to your point of reference. For an individual who works with national grid potentials 100V would appear "extra low". Likewise a high speed digital engineer working with 1.5V would consider 28V to be high voltage

From a legal point of view, at least in Europe, there is the "Low voltage directive" [2014/35/EU](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1461336551167&uri=CELEX:32014L0035)

Low voltage is defined as 50Vac --> 1000Vac ( 75Vdc --> 1500Vdc).

Below the 50Vac,75Vdc level is classed as "Extra Low Voltage"

Above 1000Vac, 1500Vdc is classed as "High Voltage"

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
    \hline IEC\ voltage\ range & AC & DC & Defining\ Risk \\\hline
      High\ Voltage & >1000V_{rms} & > 1500V & electrical\ arcing \\\hline
      Low\ Voltage & 50-1000V_{rms} & 75 - 1500V & electrical\ shock  \\\hline
      Extra-low\ voltage & <50V_{rms} & < 75V & low\ risk \\\hline
    \end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you JonRB. so when you call a system an Extra-low-voltage one, to which voltage in your system it refers? to the mains? or the power supply output? which one must be at Extra-Low-Voltage range?

Comment: As long as both the input and the output are lower than 50Vrms it can be classed as an extra-low voltage piece of equipment.  if the input is at 240V and the output < 50Vrms then it is a low-voltage i/p, extra-low voltage output. If the output is variable then the maximum it can goto defines its range (ie a 0-300V output variable supply set at 10V is still a low voltage supply NOT an extra-low voltage)